# Variables are all "undefined"

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter so I am asking for your help on this problem.

Every variable on the right of the : is undefined but I have the function inside the Users class as you can see below.

```
class Users {
  String? userId;
  String? fName;
  String? lName;
  String? address1;
  String? address2;
  String? city;
  String? state;
  String? zipCode;
  String? cellPhone;
  String? officePhone;
  String? email;
  String? companyId;
  String? companyName;
  String? mlsId;
  String? mls;

  Users(
      {this.userId,
      this.fName,
      this.lName,
      this.address1,
      this.address2,
      this.city,
      this.state,
      this.zipCode,
      this.cellPhone,
      this.officePhone,
      this.email,
      this.companyId,
      this.companyName,
      this.mlsId,
      this.mls});

  Users copyWith({
    String? userId,
    String? fName,
    String? lName,
    String? address1,
    String? address2,
    String? city,
    String? state,
    String? zipCode,
    String? cellPhone,
    String? officePhone,
    String? email,
    String? companyId,
    String? companyName,
    String? mlsId,
    String? mls,
  }) {
    return Users(
      fName: fName ?? this.fName,
      lName: lName ?? this.lName,
      address1: address1 ?? this.address1,
      address2: address2 ?? this.address2,
      city: city ?? this.city,
      state: state ?? this.state,
      zipCode: zipCode ?? this.zipCode,
      cellPhone: cellPhone ?? this.cellPhone,
      officePhone: officePhone ?? this.officePhone,
      email: email ?? this.email,
      companyId: companyId ?? this.companyId,
      companyName: companyName ?? this.companyName,
      mlsId: mlsId ?? this.mlsId,
      mls: mls ?? this.mls,
    );
  }
}

class UsersNotifier extends Notifier<Users> {
  final firestoreService = FirestoreService();
  final companyRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(('Company'));
  final userDB = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(('users'));

// **************************************************

  @override
  Users build() {
    return Users(
      userId: '',
      fName: '',
      lName: '',
      address1: '',
      address2: '',
      city: '',
      state: '',
      zipCode: '',
      cellPhone: '',
      officePhone: '',
      email: '',
      companyId: '',
      companyName: '',
      mlsId: '',
      mls: '',
    );
  }

  // functions to update class members
  void updatefName(String newfName) {
    state = state.copyWith(fName: newfName);
  }

  void updatelName(String newlName) {
    state = state.copyWith(lName: newlName);
  }

  void updateaddress1(String newaddress1) {
    state = state.copyWith(address1: newaddress1);
  }

  void updateaddress2(String newaddress2) {
    state = state.copyWith(address2: newaddress2);
  }

  void updateCity(String newCity) {
    state = state.copyWith(city: newCity);
  }

  void updateState(String newState) {
    state = state.copyWith(state: newState);
  }

  void updateZipcode(String newZipcode) {
    state = state.copyWith(zipCode: newZipcode);
  }

  void updateCellPhone(String newCellPhone) {
    state = state.copyWith(cellPhone: newCellPhone);
  }

  void updateOfficePhone(String newOfficePhone) {
    state = state.copyWith(officePhone: newOfficePhone);
  }

  void updateEmail(String newEmail) {
    state = state.copyWith(email: newEmail);
  }

  void updateCompanyId(String newCompanyId) {
    state = state.copyWith(companyId: newCompanyId);
  }
  
  void updateCompanyName(String newCompanyName) {
    state = state.copyWith(companyName: newCompanyName);
  }

  void updateMls(String newMls) {
    state = state.copyWith(mls: newMls);
  }
  
  void updateMlsId(String newMlsId) {
    state = state.copyWith(mlsId: newMlsId);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'cellPhone': cellPhone,
      'address1': address1,
      'address2': address2,
      'agency': company,
      'agencyId': companyId,
      'agentId': userId,
      'city': city,
      'fName': fName,
      'lName': lName,
      'officePhone': officePhone,
      'state': state,
      'zipCode': zipcode,
      'mls': mls,
      'mlsId': mlsId,
      'email': email
    };
  }
```

I have checked syntax and made sure all the bracks match but I still get the error. Why are the variables undefined?

I really appreciate any help you can give.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use state variable like

```dart
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'cellPhone': state.cellPhone,
      'address1': state.address1,
```

Comment: I have a NotifierProvider, would that be the right thing to use? I am just learning flutter so thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually I might not be right person to answer your comment, but I might choose StateNotifierProvider instead. give a try also you can checkout riverpod doc and their example code.

Comment: Actually, I added state. to the right side and that fixed the errors. Thank you so much